# Adding elements of a list to a dictionary at a fixed position

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list such as the one below:

```
   List = ['blue', 'Ford', 'Mustang']
```

I want to take these values and insert them into a dictionary that already has the following values:

```
 dictionary = {'Color': ' ', 'Make': ' ', Model: ' '}
```

such that my result is

```
 dictionary = {'Color': 'blue', 'Make': 'Ford', Model: 'Mustang'}
```

I am using Python3.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries, unless you are using Python 3.7+, are considered to be unordered.

Therefore, you either have to assign values to keys explicitly or use an `OrderedDict`.

#### OrderedDict

Note how we must defined the `OrderedDict` using a list of tuples.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

L = ['blue', 'Ford', 'Mustang']
d = OrderedDict([('Color', ' '), ('Make', ' '), ('Model', ' ')])

res = dict(zip(d, L))

print(res)
{'Color': 'blue', 'Make': 'Ford', 'Model': 'Mustang'}
```

#### Explicit assignment

Here we simply form a dictionary from two lists.

```
L = ['blue', 'Ford', 'Mustang']
K = ['Color', 'Make', 'Model']

res = dict(zip(K, L))
```

Note there is no significant performance advantage of updating an existing dictionary versus forming a new dictionary via `dict(zip(..., ...))`. Both processes will have O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to specify exactly which value from the list goes with which key from the dictionary. So do:

```
l = ['blue', 'Ford', 'Mustang']
d = {'Color': ' ', 'Make': ' ', 'Model': ' '}

print "Before inserting:",d

d['Color']=l[0]
d['Make']=l[1]
d['Model']=l[2]

print "After inserting:",d
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Code, first I convert the dictionary into a list and converge the two lists together to get the desired output. This is my Code:

```
list_1 = ['blue', 'Ford', 'Mustang']
dictionary = {'Color': ' ', 'Make': ' ', 'Model': ' '}.keys()
converter = dict(zip(dictionary, list_1))
print(converter)
```